# How to remove the Gtalk Plugin completely?

Tags: 14.04, uninstall, gtalk

I have installed Gtalk Plugin in Ubuntu 14.04.

How to remove that completely?

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: No, I mean from a PPA or a deb file?

Comment: Via Terminal, Sorry I have forgotten @Ron

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove GTalk Plugin completely by:

```
sudo apt-get purge google-talkplugin
```

From `man apt-get`:

```
 purge
           purge is identical to remove except that packages are removed and purged (any
           configuration files are deleted too).
```

So this will remove everything regarding the package.

Comment: Thanks a lot@ Ron. It worked. But will  it remove completely and how to Check that?